# How to use hot deployment and development mode with jboss and gwt

Tags: maven-2, gwt, jboss, deployment

How to configure eclipse to hot deploy to jboss server side code? And how to configure google eclipse plugin to use development mode with jboss and the hot deployed code? What projects should I create?

Could someone give me step by step configuration how to do it.

I just want to use ejb/jpa/jms(optional) on the server side with hot deployment and at the same time to use ejbs in the gwt rpc implementations(or gwt-dispatch lib) with development mode. And at the end, i also want to build every thing with maven for production. Is this possible?

The three

1. gwt development mode
2. jboss hot deployment
3. mvn build and dependencies management

separately work, but combined how?

Everything I tried was unsuccessful.